# issue using dequeueing UICollectionViewCell and TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I'm seeing the following when I use

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "book", for: indexPath) as! BookTableViewCell


cell.cellIndex = indexPath
cell.dataSource = self
cell.delegate = self
var books = [Book]();

let count = self.enterpriseBooks.count;
if (count > 0) {
    if (indexPath.section <= self.enterpriseBooks.count) {
        var number = 0;
        for (listName, _) in self.enterpriseBooks {
            if (number == (indexPath.section - 1)) {
                if let listName = listName as? String, let booksArr = self.enterpriseBooks[listName] {
                    books = booksArr
                }
                break;
            }
            number += 1;
        }
    }
}

if (indexPath.section == (count + 1)) {
    books = nytbooks;
} else if (indexPath.section == (count + 2)) {
    books = trendingbooks;
} else if (indexPath.section == (count + 3)) {
    books = newbooks
}
if (books.count > 0) {
    if (cell.collectionView === nil) {
        cell.addCollectionView();
    }
    cell.collectionView.reloadData()
}
return cell
```

I'm I using dequeueReusableCell correctly? I'm not sure what's causing the layout to be completely screwed up especially as I scroll down.

Comment: The plan with collections, like `UITableView`, is to give the data source as little work as possible (unlike in your code). Your job is to do all of the data parsing and prep work before you load the table's data. Then when the table has been loaded, all the data source is tasked with doing is injecting the cell with ready-to-go data. Not all of the cells are loaded in a table, only the visible ones. Therefore, when the user scrolls through a table, the data source is forever adding and removing cells through the data source. Therefore, you need to keep it and the cells as slim as possible.

Comment: why are you doing fors in `cellForRowAt` function? clean your data in other functions and then reload the tableView